# React Js Special Character Replacement

Tags: javascript

Currently I am pulling data from a Json and displaying specific parts of it. 
I am able to display the data but one of the numbers is showing like this,

```
0)
```

which wont work i need it to display with just a

```
 0
```

I figured id be a good idea to just do the

```
.replace(/")"/g," ")
```

method but it doesnt work in this case. 
Any ideas on what I can do to get it working ?

Comment: Can you provide the code that renders it?

Comment: You can also use slice or substr() methods

Answer (score 0):

Since `)` is a special character in RegEx, you have to scape `)` by prefixing `\` to match the character literally. Try

```
.replace(/\)/g, "")
```

Comment: @JakobLong, does my answer solves your problem? if so, may I request you to accept the answer by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in......thanks.